# Words run over div on Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, overflow

I have a div contain list of page.

On Chrome it works well with breakdown.

But on Safari it runs over div.

How can i fix it please give me advice.

This is code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
}
#forumng-buttons form {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.paging {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.paging {
    word-spacing: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="forumng-buttons"><form action="editpost.php" method="get" class="forumng-post-button"><div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="17"><input type="submit" value="Start a new discussion"></div></form></div>
<div class="paging">Page:  <span class="current-page">1</span>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=2">2</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=3">3</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=4">4</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=5">5</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=6">6</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=7">7</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=8">8</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=9">9</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=10">10</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=11">11</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=12">12</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=13">13</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=14">14</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=15">15</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=16">16</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=17">17</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=2">2</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=3">3</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=4">4</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=5">5</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=6">6</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=7">7</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=8">8</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=9">9</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=10">10</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=11">11</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=12">12</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=13">13</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=14">14</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=15">15</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=16">16</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=17">17</a><a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=18">18</a> ...<a class="last" href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=24">24</a>  <a class="next" href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=2">Next</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: div.paging {
    word-spacing: .5em; word-break:break-all;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with this line of css:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Remove the `width` setting and the `div` naturally occupies all the space it can, causing its contents to wrap around to fit inside the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
}
#forumng-buttons form {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.paging {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.paging {
    word-spacing: .5em;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="forumng-buttons"><form action="editpost.php" method="get" class="forumng-post-button"><div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="17"><input type="submit" value="Start a new discussion"></div></form></div>
<div class="paging">Page:  <span class="current-page">1</span>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=2">2</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=3">3</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=4">4</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=5">5</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=6">6</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=7">7</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=8">8</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=9">9</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=10">10</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=11">11</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=12">12</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=13">13</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=14">14</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=15">15</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=16">16</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=17">17</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=2">2</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=3">3</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=4">4</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=5">5</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=6">6</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=7">7</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=8">8</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=9">9</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=10">10</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=11">11</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=12">12</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=13">13</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=14">14</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=15">15</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=16">16</a>  <a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=17">17</a><a href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=18">18</a> ...<a class="last" href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=24">24</a>  <a class="next" href="view.php?id=17&amp;sort=d&amp;page=2">Next</a></div>
</div>
```